# Thermodynamics isothermal reversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

In isothermal reversible process is pressure constant along with temperature if  not then why change in enthalpy is zero as the formula $\Delta H = n C_{p} m \Delta T$ valid for constant pressure?
And if pressure is constant then why not $\Delta H = q = 0$?

Comment: A reversible isothermal process can’t be constant pressure

Answer (score 1):

1. For reversible isothermal process the heat is not zero, it is
   $$Q = T \Delta S$$
2. If the process is also isobaric, as in a phase transition, then
   $$ Q = T \Delta S_\text{vap} = \Delta H_\text{vap}$$
   Notice here that $Q = \Delta H$ (since $P$ is constant) but $\Delta H \neq C_P \Delta T$ because we are dealing with latent heat.

Answer (score 0):

Is pressure constant during the reversible isothermal process? No, only temperature is constant. The reason why $\Delta H$ is zero is that $\Delta T $ is zero.
Consider H equation
$$H = U +PV$$
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + P\Delta V + V\Delta P$$
For a constant pressure process $\Delta P =0$ thus,
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + P\Delta V$$
which is non-zero unless $\Delta T = 0$

For a constant pressure process, heat can go into the system thus, $q \not = 0$.